# Computer Flashes Out?

Tags: netbook, sleep, display

We have a strange problem with our computers at my school. They are all Latitude 2100 Netbooks. At random points (I can't seem to find a pattern) the screen will turn a single color (red, green, black, brown, etc.) To fix this, the computer must be put to sleep, and brought back up.

They have integrated graphics, but I can't imagine that if it was a bug with the computer itself, that every single computer would do this. Is there any way I could find out the problem that's causing this. Some diagnostic tool? Thanks.

Edit: Forgot, they all have windows.

Comment: What OS are they running? Windows? Linux?

Comment: They all use Windows.

Answer (score 1):

What are the settings for the screen saver? Possibly set to display a single color page?  Saw this as a joke one time but with various error messages.  It was "better"(and similar to your issue)  because many of the systems did not exit the screen saver when the mouse was moved or a key pressed and they had to be power cycled.

Comment: No, the color seems to be random, and you can set the screen saver perfectly fine. It happens at other times, not on the screen saver.

Comment: Worth a shot.  Good luck!